# How can I synchronise configs such as tsconfig, eslintconfig, prettier across different projects?

Tags: node.js, git, version-control, config

My team develops different micro services with Node, using tools such as Typescript, ESLint, and Prettier among others. These tools have configuration files that are located in the project root. (This is important, because git submodules, as far as I understand, can only be used on selected sub-folders).

We change this configuration files from time to time, as our tools improve and offer new capabilities. However, its tiresome to copy these new settings to all the different services we maintain. What's a good way to sync them between different projects and keep things DRY?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a npm-package and use it with all projects. That way you will also get versioning for your settings.

Comment: Are you sure that I can use NPM package for configuration files? How do I point these tools to use this NPM package instead of looking in the project root?

Comment: You can write an install script in a npm package that will copy all necessary rule files in the root of a project, for instance